# 2×2 & 2×3 that join by ends

Tags: part-identification

[image]
Bought a batch & found these, what are they called? What are their uses?

Answer (score 7):

These are various modified Technic Bricks with "[Joint Ball Half](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=Joint%20Ball%20Half#T=A)" and "[Rotation Joint Socket](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/search.page?q=Rotation%20Joint%20Socket#T=A)" features as they are called on Bricklink. [Technic Rotation Joint Ball Loop with Two Perpendicular Pins with Friction](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=47455#T=C) are the connectors for this type of elements. Although there are more ways to attach them. These elements have been used in large number of sets, originally coming in brick-built figures like [Danju (8770)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=8770-1#T=P):

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I've also 2 for his lower leg, 2 1/2's attach to brick.